# Solving the integral $\int x\sqrt{1+x}\ dx $

Tags: integration, substitution

I need to solve the following indefinite integral by substitution

$$\int x\sqrt{1+x}\  dx $$with $u=1+x$
Can anyone help me by showing me detailed step by step solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. What have you tried yourself? It will help you more if you explain in more detail. By the way, doing substitution is overkill here, since $x\sqrt{1+x}=(1+x-1)\sqrt{1+x}=(1+x)^{3/2}-\sqrt{1+x}$, which is easily integrated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**HINT:** If $u=1+x$, then $x = u - 1$ and you can substitute those into the integral (of course $du=dx$):

$$\int{(u-1)\sqrt{u}\  du}=\int{(u\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{u})\  du}=\int{(u^{\frac{3}{2}}-u^{\frac{1}{2}})\  du}$$

I won't go further, because I trust that you can finish the last integral on your own. :)

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful! I got it now.

Answer (score 6):

Given $u = 1 + x $, then $dx = du $ and so your integral becomes

$$ \int (u-1) \sqrt{u} du = \int u \sqrt{u} du - \int \sqrt{u} du$$

Now, use power rule:

$$ \int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C$$